# There is evidence that domesticated animals (cats or dogs) understand human language?

Tags: psycholinguistics, language-acquisition

Some pet owners seem to be able to speak to their cats or dogs. Is there any evidence that animals understand human languages?

**EDIT**: By *understand*, i mean understanding of spoken language and relatively long sentence. We are not talking about understanding of some reserved, isolated words (like run command or attack command for dogs). It's more like understanding of *discourse* with all methaphors and grammatical constructions and perhaps all this *Sprachspiel* (Wittgenstein).

Comment: Welcome to SE Linguistics! That's a very interesting question! We encourage posters to do a certain amount of research on their own before they post their question. Have you tried to google the subject and could you please add the information you have found to your question?

Comment: Yes, i've read some articles on wikipedia: [Animal language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_language), [Ethology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethology), [Cognitive ethology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_ethology)

Comment: These articles contain answers to your question, such as "Eventually, Gua [a chimpanzee] was able to respond to around 95 words and phrases, but she was never able to acquire the words or phrases." If you don't find this answer satisfying you may need to modify your original question (by using the 'edit' link immediately below the question).

Comment: Yes, i know about primates (human-primate communication) and communication between animals (bee dances, whale songs, birds songs, meerkat signals). But i've especially interested about communication between human and domesticated animals (like cats and dogs). I think i should edit my original question..

Comment: The restriction on domesticated animals is a step forward, but your question is still very vague. What do you mean by 'understand'? Dogs can be trained to follow commands such as 'sit' and distinguish them from other commands. In that sense they do understand human language. But if you tell your dog that the band at last night's concert was terrible I don't quite think it will be able to grasp the concept.

Comment: _Understand_, especially in the context of animal subjects, has a **very** broad range of meanings. You're up against the [Turing test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test) at one end of the range, and the [Kluger Hans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans) phenomenon at the other end. I tend to think that humans and pets can achieve either a convincing imitation of real understanding or the real thing -- in the appropriate circumstances, like anything else. But how could one tell the difference?

Comment: In fact, by "understand" i mean "understand spoken language". And this totally not _Kluger Hans phenomenon_ it's more like Turing test. Particularly, i would like to know about understanding of long sentence with big amount of words. Sorry to be ambiguous.

Comment: It's still ambiguous. How could a dog understand "language"? Could he understand a romance novel? A poem? A grammar paper? And how could one tell? Certainly dogs can memorize a large number of spoken words for different things; that's been proven. But this is not language; humans don't retrieve dolls on hearing the doll's name spoken. They can, but mostly they have other uses for spoken language, some of which involve human understanding. As Wittgenstein put it, if lions could talk, we couldn't understand them.

Comment: @bokryonok Even in Turing tests you need to be wary of the [Chinese room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room) phenomenon where a man in a room with a Chinese-English dictionary can, given a series of Chinese symbols and enough time, convince the people outside the room that he speaks fluent Chinese even if he doesn't.

Comment: @jlawler Yes, that i'm looking for - some research  on human-animal (dog, cats) communication, when the researchers try to exclude all those factors (Chinese room, Kluger Hans phenomenon) and see what happened. For me, model situation for this expirement -   Pet owner question: "I should buy a truck for my farm, but a red sportcar it's more fun, should i'v buy a truck or a sportcar?"   Pet answer: "You should go to the personal finance & money stackexchange and learn about basic concepts, stupid!". Is it possible?

Comment: @bokrynok No, it's not - at least not in the way that i suspect you mean. There's an instance of a collie having been convincingly shown to have memorised around 1000 individual words (http://www.wofford.edu/psychology/chaser/), but that's the most impressive case i know about. There's absolutely zero evidence of any understanding of grammar. I'd recommend reading 'Doctor Dolittle's Delusion' by Stephen Anderson : http://www.amazon.com/Doctor-Dolittles-Delusion-Uniqueness-Language/dp/0300115253/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1378375971&sr=8-1&keywords=doctor+dolittle%27s+delusion

Comment: @PElliott, yes it's understanding of grammar and i say understanding of discourse. This book of Anderson it's exactly what i need, thank you. Nice citation: "Dr. Dolittle had it wrong, says the author of this fascinating book: animals cannot use language. Stephen Anderson explains the difference between communication and language and shows that animals do not have the cognitive capacities necessary to acquire language".

Comment: I don't think such evidences exist. I think if it could be proven, cognitive linguistics theory would be different. There's no way to know what's in a dog's mind, but if they were able to decode syntax, and understand semantics, don't you think they'd learn how to speak too?

Answer (score -2):

There is (to me) almost indisputable evidence that parrots in particular understand and can create sentences and coin words. Look at what Pepperburg did with Alex. And with word buttons, unless the whole thing is faked or the result of random button presses that are presented in videos selectively, it seems very compelling (to me) that the dog Bunny (a poodle mix trained since puppyhood to use them) can make sentences and understands abstract concepts like time. You can watch Bunny on Youtube. She is also not the only dog (or cat) that seems to be able to do this but she does seems to be the most able. The parrot research is decades old but the dog stuff dates from I think not coincidentally the Covid era when bored pet owners started to experiment on their own, sometimes in collaboration with scientists.

This is the Wikipedia article about Alex, the parrot trained and studied by Pepperberg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_(parrot). Bunny the dog can be searched on Youtube.

Comment: the soundboard videos are all coming from advocates of the practice, an so, whether intentionally or not, likely only include the best uses of the buttons. Regardless, none of the videos show any indication of grammar, just some understanding of the meanings of individual buttons (similarly primate sign language experiments don't seem to have shown any ability to learn the grammar of sign languages, only the meaning of signs), which may be combined in novel albeit unstructured ways

Comment: @Tristan: How do you account for the apparent language usage of Alex? Not to mention literally thousands of anecdotes from other parrot owners? It is accepted that crows show cognitive abilities that are on par with human 7 year olds -- why is language so hard to believe?

Comment: I do not know those cases, and so did not address them. I only addressed the instances of sound boards as with Bunny, and with primate sign language experiments

Comment: @Tristan: anyone interested in animal use of language would enjoy reading about Pepperberg and Alex -- she is a PHD in chemistry who decided to switch to studying parrots and started doing this almost 40 years ago -- remarkable results.